# Condtionally prepend a character to input lines based on their first character

Tags: linux, shell, csv, sed

For a dataset in a csv file where the first column is often empty, I'd like to programmatically insert an additional comma into every line that does not begin with a double quotation mark.
From the sample below, you will see that only certain lines begin with `"` and those are the lines I'd like to ignore. Every other line should get an additional `,`.

```
"1967 Universe",1967,"1,141.0",650.6,73.0,417.5,222.6,119.6,309.8,176.0,390.8,225.0,217.8,130.0
,1968,"1,353.4",694.7,84.3,574.4,234.8,119.2,350.1,182.1,477.3,233.9,291.1,159.5
,1969,"1,322.3",624.8,85.2,612.4,215.8,104.7,317.0,149.9,470.5,215.6,319.0,154.6
,1970,"1,351.5",646.8,88.1,616.7,218.3,93.1,287.4,148.1,502.9,246.5,342.9,159.1
,1971,"1,924.6",906.1,132.9,885.7,303.6,127.3,421.1,208.1,725.4,338.6,474.6,232.1
"1972 Universe",1972,"2,218.9","1,033.1",148.6,"1,037.2",333.3,147.3,440.8,230.1,905.4,391.5,539.3,264.3
,1973,"1,819.5",882.1,117.0,820.5,271.9,141.6,361.4,197.5,763.2,323.9,423.1,219.0
,1974,"1,074.4",643.8,64.4,366.2,165.4,97.2,241.3,154.5,390.1,223.7,277.6,168.4
,1975,939.2,675.5,63.8,199.8,129.5,92.6,241.5,169.3,292.7,222.8,275.5,190.8
,1976,"1,296.2",893.6,93.1,309.5,152.4,111.2,326.1,219.4,401.7,292.6,416.0,270.5
,1977,"1,690.0","1,126.1",121.3,442.7,181.9,126.8,402.4,269.3,561.1,370.1,544.6,359.9
"1978 Universe",1978,"1,800.5","1,182.6",130.6,487.3,194.4,132.9,388.0,260.8,667.6,439.3,550.5,349.6
,1979,"1,551.8",981.5,125.4,444.8,166.9,110.2,289.1,182.4,628.0,392.1,467.7,296.7
,1980,"1,190.6",710.4,114.5,365.7,117.9,75.7,192.0,107.9,561.9,333.0,318.9,193.7
,1981,985.5,564.3,101.8,319.4,109.8,65.7,133.3,78.3,491.1,270.7,251.3,149.5
,1982,"1,000.5",546.4,88.3,365.8,106.7,65.7,126.3,67.6,543.5,281.1,224.1,132.0
,1983,"1,605.2",901.5,133.7,570.1,164.1,112.3,187.8,117.4,862.9,443.0,390.4,228.6
```

I think this could be done with `sed`, but I'm not familiar enough with Regex to know how to do a conditional replace.

The only example I've found which is similar is

```
sed -ri 's/[^,]+/REPLACEMENT/' file.csv
```

so it would probably look like

```
sed -ri 's/[^,]+/,/' file.csv
```

but I don't think that's right

```
sed 's/\,/\,,/'
```

almost works but it replaces the comma after every first instance of the comma which isn't what I'm after. Example:

```
"2004 Universe",,2004,"2,070.1","1,613.4",90.4,366.2,197.0,131.8,370.5,295.5,960.8,756.1,541.9,430.0
,,2005,"2,155.3","1,682.0",84.0,389.3,203.8,126.6,353.9,278.7,"1,039.0",826.8,558.6,450.0
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Where should the comma be added?  At the start of the line, or at the end, or somewhere else?  Ideally, you should both describe where the comma goes and show the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The example at the end implies that the comma should be _prepended_ to the line; I've amended the title accordingly.

Comment: @mklement0 — agreed that it all implies 'prepended', but the question shouldn't really imply it; it should state it.  The trouble with the last example is that there's a double comma after the string field, so it is actually an example of the last `sed` not working as desired — rather than what is actually desired.  I agree the inference is not hard, but the best questions don't make those attempting to answer infer anything (at least about the desired output).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed. Given that I had no doubt about the intent and that there were already answers based on that intent, I revised the question myself in this case, but I get that it's (a) generally worth letting the OP know what the question lacks and (b) encouraging them to improve it themselves. Our comments now still serve purpose (a).

Comment: Thank you very much, I agree that I could have been more eloquent with my wording. When it's after midnight and your head is torn apart trying to solve a problem, it's sometimes difficult to put words together in a sentence. In future, I will question with a "how can I get from this - to this -" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extended regex option `-r` is not needed

```
sed -i 's/^,/,&/' file
```

will insert an additional comma on the lines starting with comma.
circumflex indicates start of line.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>For a *positive* formulation of the problem - prepend `,` to all lines that *start with `,`* - see [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36538475/45375).</sup>

To prepend `,` to all lines that *do not start with `"`*, try the following:

```
sed -i -r 's/^[^"]/,&/' file.csv
```

- `^[^"]` captures any single character that is not a `"` (`[^"]`) at the beginning of the line (`^`) and replaces it with a `,`, followed by the string that matched the regex (`&`), i.e., that line's first char. (which in your sample input is also a `,`).

  - Note the potentially confusing distinct uses of `^`: as the start-of-line anchor right after the opening delimiter `/` on the one hand, and as the negation operator as the first character inside the bracket expression (character set) (`[^...]`) on the other.
  - Note that nonstandard option `-r` activates support for EREs (*extended* regular expressions), whereas `sed` by default expects BREs (*basic* regular expressions).
    The above works without `-r` as well, but if using EREs is an option, they're preferable, because they offer more features and their syntax is much more like that of regular expressions in other languages.
- Any lines that do not match, i.e., any lines that *do* start with `"`, are passed through as-is.

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
sed -ri 's/[^,]+/,/' file.csv
```

matches *one or more* (`+`) characters other than `,` *anywhere* on the line, because the bracket expression (character set) `[^,]` is not *anchored* to the beginning of the string (with a `^` right after the `/`).

Aside from that, your replacement string does not incorporate the *matched* string, so it would *replace* the match with `,` instead of prepending to it.

```
sed 's/\,/\,,/'
```

again lacks the *anchoring* of the regex at the beginning of the string, and will therefore replace the first `,` *anywhere* on the line.
(As an aside, neither `\` is needed in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer mklement0, You've helped me understand why I encountered the problem and how to solve it!. I agree that the positive formulation of the problem may be the best approach compared to what I was ultimately trying to do.  
  
I will also do more reading on regex so that I can better understand matches and anchoring!  
I attempted to accept both answers as a solution but it would only let me choose one :\

Answer (score 0):

**file.csv:**

```
"1967 Universe",1967,"1,141.0",650.6,73.0,417.5,222.6,119.6,309.8,176.0,390.8,225.0,217.8,130.0
,1968,"1,353.4",694.7,84.3,574.4,234.8,119.2,350.1,182.1,477.3,233.9,291.1,159.5
,1969,"1,322.3",624.8,85.2,612.4,215.8,104.7,317.0,149.9,470.5,215.6,319.0,154.6
,1970,"1,351.5",646.8,88.1,616.7,218.3,93.1,287.4,148.1,502.9,246.5,342.9,159.1
,1971,"1,924.6",906.1,132.9,885.7,303.6,127.3,421.1,208.1,725.4,338.6,474.6,232.1
"1972 Universe",1972,"2,218.9","1,033.1",148.6,"1,037.2",333.3,147.3,440.8,230.1,905.4,391.5,539.3,264.3
,1973,"1,819.5",882.1,117.0,820.5,271.9,141.6,361.4,197.5,763.2,323.9,423.1,219.0
```

Use:

```
$ sed 's/^,/,,/' file.csv
```

**Output:**

```
"1967 Universe",1967,"1,141.0",650.6,73.0,417.5,222.6,119.6,309.8,176.0,390.8,225.0,217.8,130.0
,,1968,"1,353.4",694.7,84.3,574.4,234.8,119.2,350.1,182.1,477.3,233.9,291.1,159.5
,,1969,"1,322.3",624.8,85.2,612.4,215.8,104.7,317.0,149.9,470.5,215.6,319.0,154.6
,,1970,"1,351.5",646.8,88.1,616.7,218.3,93.1,287.4,148.1,502.9,246.5,342.9,159.1
,,1971,"1,924.6",906.1,132.9,885.7,303.6,127.3,421.1,208.1,725.4,338.6,474.6,232.1
"1972 Universe",1972,"2,218.9","1,033.1",148.6,"1,037.2",333.3,147.3,440.8,230.1,905.4,391.5,539.3,264.3
,,1973,"1,819.5",882.1,117.0,820.5,271.9,141.6,361.4,197.5,763.2,323.9,423.1,219.0
```